# How to print and sum only numbers from HTML code?(Python)

Tags: python, html, numbers

The problem is that I cant get out numbers from the HTML code.

Comment: You look for <span> with a className comments. The HTML string you provide has no elements as such. I would suggest you to read more about HTML and BeautifulSoup

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = str(input())
soup = BeautifulSoup(url,"html.parser")
data = soup.find_all('td')
numbers = [d.text for d in data if d.text.isdigit()] # if the text of the td element is a number, include it in the list assigned to the variable 'numbers'
print(numbers)
>>> ['23', '40']
```

Essentially, break it down into smaller steps:

- Separate out all of the HTML elements that could possibly contain the data you're after (in this case, `<td>` elements)
- For each of those elements, check if it contains a digit using the str.isnumber() method: [str.isdigit() doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit)

Comment: Try it now - had to move around the list comprehension syntax.

Comment: it's certainly possible, but the approach would depend on your needs. can you just not use beautifulsoup in particular or all HTML parsing libraries?

Comment: isdigit won't account for floats.

Comment: @n1c9 for example, the task is similar to this one, but need to do this task without beautifulsoup only with finding numbers or replacing, could you give me some hint, please?